# How to get/ retrieve the lock screen password instead of completely removing lock screen password by using ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am just a newbie and learning and tried searching online but that attempt was futile so at last asking it..
I know how to remove password without any third party software through ADB and USB debugging and "adb shell rm /data/system/gesture.key" so can anyone explain abit clearly how to just know what the password it without removing the lock.

Comment: that sounds like a massive security concern. are passwords even stored in clear text anyway ?

Comment: Actually this method requires us to enable USB debugging in developer options and gives us a security notice so i dont think its a security concern